# Centering a enumerate list label

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

In this code as [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Customizing_lists):

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Exercise \arabic*:]
   \item 5 + 7 = 12
   \item 9 + 1 = 10
   \item 2 * 2 = 4
\end{enumerate}
```

I want the text **Exercise** (with its number) to be center-align and the content after that to be `below` and left-align. Anybody can help. Thanks.

Comment: You mean so that `\item 5 + 7 = 12` translates into "**Exercise 1** <newline> 5 + 7 = 12". Or is each enumerate block prefaced by the **Exercise** ?

Comment: @jon I mean: Exercise 1 <newline> 5 + 7 = 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve the desired results:

[image]

### Improvements

- Note that there is a `-5.0pt` tweak to the `labelwidth` to compensate for the with of the label. This really should be computed based on other `enumitem` lengths.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\SetLabelAlign{center}{\hss#1\hss}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Exercise \arabic*},
    align=center,
    labelwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-5.0pt\relax,
    leftmargin=!,
    style=unboxed,
    ]
   \item 5 + 7 = 12
   \item 9 + 1 = 10
   \item 2 * 2 = 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank Peter Grill and Andrew very much. This helps resolve my problem. But I don't understand why you can add those things. What lines in what pages in what documents you use for the added code above. I have read over and over enumitem documentation but I can't resolve the problem. You two great!

Comment: @Exdata: This really is not what lists are intended for thus I think it'll be difficult to find such an example in the documentation. But you could search the `enumitem` documentation for `\SetLabelAlign` where there is a related example without the second `hss` and meaning of `labelwidth`.

Answer (score 1):

Why in an enumerate environment? I might be inclined to cheat if that is the input (though I hope it is not if you are actually typesetting math).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\newcounter{exercise}
\setcounter{exercise}{0}
\renewcommand{\theexercise}{\arabic{exercise}}
\newcommand\iitem[1]{%
%\begingroup
  \refstepcounter{exercise}%
  \parindent0pt
  {\centering
    \textbf{Exercise \theexercise}\par} #1%
%\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\section{S One}

\lipsum[1]%\label{zzz}

\iitem 5 + 7 = 12

\iitem 9 + 1 = 10

\iitem 2 * 2 = 4\label{asdf}

See Exercise \ref{asdf}.
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Of course, as soon as you want to include real math, you're going to need far more robust commands....